# How to run a Linux distro within an LXC container on Android?

Tags: android, linux, lxc

I'm trying to run a Linux distro such as Ubuntu within an LXC container on Android. Ubuntu for Android worked using LXC, but they never released the code.

Answer (score 4):

This writeup about how to run LXC on the new NVidia Android based Shield TV box might give you an idea...

http://www.videomap.it/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1604

Comment: Great! I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.halium.org/en/latest/porting/install-build/index.html

https://docs.halium.org/en/latest/porting/build-sources.html

It seems that project Halium, if it works on your device, let you run GNU/Linux distributions under Android LXC Containers.

Comment: that works the other way around it runs android in LXC under glinux distributions. the purpose of halium is to use android to access the hardware